# Using dispatched actions

Tags: react-native, redux

I have this on the bottom of my main file:

```
export default connect(state => ({
    state: state.firebaseReducer
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(firebaseActions, dispatch)
  })
)(Routing);
```

And this is my reducer that I imported

```
const initialState = null;
export function firebaseRef(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'FIREBASE_REF_SET':
    return action.value;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Action:

```
export function setFirebaseRef(ref) {
  return {
    type: 'FIREBASE_REF_SET',
    value: ref
  };
}
```

But when I try to do this in my main file:

```
componentDidMount() {
  state.setFirebaseRef(ref);
}
```

It says "Can't find variable: state" . Am I calling it the wrong way? I want to be able to call the setFireBaseRef action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**connect** injects parts of state and dispatch into props. You want to *dispatch* the action using:

```
this.props.dispatch(setFireBaseRef(ref))
```

Or, assuming `firebaseActions`contains `setFireBaseRef`, you can just do:

```
this.props.actions.setFireBaseRef(ref)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! And thanks for the explanation.